# What do these Xcode warnings mean?

Tags: xcode, debugging, core-data, nsobject

I’m getting the following warnings in Xcode when building my app (app runs just fine however):

> Could not associate debug note to atom
> l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_NSObject
>
> Could not associate debug note to atom
> l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_REFERENCE_$_CAAction
>
> Could not associate debug note to atom
> l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_CAAnimationDelegate
>
> Could not associate debug note to atom
> l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_REFERENCE_$_CAAnimationDelegate
>
> Could not associate debug note to atom
> l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_REFERENCE_$_NSObject
>
> Could not associate debug note to atom
> l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_CAAction

I’ve searched the internet but haven’t found any similar threads on this warnings. Maybe someone can help out :)?

Tinkering around with Core Data in my app and getting this warnings. I think they appeared after I played around with the xcode debugger. Not sure tho.

Comment: Happening a bunch w/Xcode 17 Beta 2 as well

Answer (score 1):

just a note.. it happens when archving, not in debug.
may be optimisations remove debug info ? ;(

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally occur when Xcode is unable to associate debug information to specific symbols or references.

try to do **clean and rebuild your project** or **restart the Xcode**.

Comment: I think this doesn't always work, is not a proper fix I'd say.